# AsyncHttpResponseHandler error message

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error message

> Error:(137, 56) error:  is not abstract and
>   does not override abstract method
>   onFailure(int,Header[],byte[],Throwable) in AsyncHttpResponseHandler

```
  client.post("http://Your Ip Address or Localhost:8080/ImageUploadWebApp/uploading.jsp",
            params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {

                    prgDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                                      String content) {

                    prgDialog.hide();

                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Requested resource not found",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

What is the issue with the code?

Thank you

Comment: Your method parameters are different from the abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

@James is correct, your method parameters are not correct, the error message explicitly states this.  I don't know how you don't get an error for your onSuccess as well.

I'm guessing your are using the [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) async http library?

```
mClient.post(null, locationURL, se, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

            AppLog.d("TAG", "Data post update success");

         }
     @Override
     public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        AppLog.d("TAG", "Data post update failure");

     }
  });
```